# Android hide images

Tags: java, android, performance, android-webview

Morning I create one app with *baker framework*, today his stay in play store, but a I need upload his. My problem is when I touch in anywhere place on screen images hide, I used web view.

Exist something in android guarding memory ? In my app images is like that:

android:visibility="visible"

I can't understand.

Comment: could you post some code?

Comment: Andres, I think is not about the code, because I have problem in all pages, what if devise guard memory for himself? Because the framework compile for 2 platform(IOS and Android)